# Oracle synonym alternatives in H2?

Tags: oracle, h2, synonym

I want to use H2 for unit test and want to copy the structure (as close as possible) from a oracle database.

I found some synonyms created in the oracle database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE SYNONYM "SYSTEM1"."SYS2_USER_VIEW" FOR "SYSTEM2"."USER_VIEW";
```

AFAIK, H2 does not have any support on creating synonyms. Any alternatives or workarounds to achieve the similar?

Edit: I am using H2 version 1.4.196 according to my maven settings

Comment: Another good example why using a different DBMS for testing and production isn't really sensible

Comment: ikr, even if I got it work, the result maybe not reliable due to the actual difference with the real db.

But before I change my codes or anything else, I just want to see if I can find any workarounds so that I can avoid making too much changes to the projects I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 has an **undocumented**

```sql
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] SYNONYM [ IF NOT EXISTS ] synonymName FOR targetTableOrView
```

command.

But H2 does not support additional clauses from recent versions of Oracle database, such as `EDITIONABLE`.

Comment: Sadly I got syntax error: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM[*] ""TEST_SYNONYM"" FOR ""TEST_VIEW"""; expected "FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX";

Comment: What version of H2 database do you use? They aren't supported by legacy versions. H2 supports them since 1.4.197 I guess. You really should use the latest version (1.4.199 for now).

Comment: Just edited my question. I am using 1.4.196 I believe. Will see if this works after an update.

Comment: 1.4.200 is not supporting synonym for sequences. Any idea?